# Драйвер под Android

Tags: java, android, микроконтроллеры

Реализуем проект под Android по производственной тематике. Появилась необходимость подключения самопального микроконтроллера с дисплеем на борту к Android приложению, путем подключения по USB-(путем USB-RS232) так как блок с микроконтроллером COM интерфейс имеет. Накидали тестовую консольную программку на C# под ПК,где путем обмена пакетами байтов(ascii и т.д.) читаем пакеты с микроконтроллера и пишем ей(Выводим на дисплей что-нибудь). А как быть с Android? не хватает опыта понять, нужно ли писать драйвер под Android,а потом по тому же протоколу как с компьютерной программкой обмениваться с микроконтроллером? Либо же драйвер не нужен?То есть можно просто подключить микроконтроллер к планшету и обмениваться data пакетами?

Comment: Планшет ваш умеет быть USB-хостом, так же как компьютер? С этого стоит начать.

Comment: otg поддерживается

Answer (score 1):

Если у Вас CDC USB класс, то андроид его поддерживает без "сторонних" драйверов.
Главное это проверить наличие системных файлов 
/system/etc/permissions/**android.hardware.usb.host.xml** и **handheld_core_hardware.xml**(tablet_core_hardware.xml) с содержимым:

```
<permissions>
    <feature name="android.hardware.usb.host">
</feature></permissions>
```

Так же в проект(ресурсы) можете добавить файл device_filter.xml с содержимым:

```
<resources>
    <usb-device vendor-id="65535" product-id="65535" />
</resources>
```

PID и VID в десятичном виде.
Дальше пользуете стандартные классы для работы с usb (android.hardware.usb.*).